# Is there an easier way to get the (first) Parsley.js focusedField element after validation?

Tags: parsley.js

Is there an easier way to get the (first invalid) Parsley.js focusedField element after validation?

My code below works, but I am looking for an easier/better way to retrieve that element.

When `form:error` occurs, the Parsley `formInstance._focusedField` object contains this information, but `console.log(formInstance._focusedField)` always returns `undefined`.

My issue: I have some semantic ui dropdown (styled select boxes) which are not receiving focus() because they are hidden. (i.e. The form does not jump to the first error field if the select is hidden)

Each ui dropdown auto generates an input element for user searching, so if the element `is('select:hidden')`, I focus on the next closest input.

For this example i have `data-parsley-focus="none"` set on the form.

```js
window.Parsley.on('form:error', function(formInstance) {
    for (var i = 0; i < formInstance.fields.length; i++) {
        var field = formInstance.fields[i];
        if (true !== field.validationResult && field.validationResult.length > 0 && 'undefined' === typeof field.options.noFocus) {
            var focusedField = field.$element;

            if ($(focusedField).is('select:hidden')) {
                $(focusedField).parent().find('input').focus();
            } else {
                $(focusedField).focus();
            }

            \\focus on first invalid element 
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Direct answer**:

You could listen to `form:validate`, and clear a variable `firstField`, and set that variable on `field:error` if it's not already set.

**Better answer**:

The actual problem is that `focus()` on the hidden field doesn't work. I'd suggest you fix *that* instead of hacking `parsley`... Find these hidden inputs, listen for `focus` on them and "redirect" the focus correctly.

**Ultimate answer**:

Fix the problem for everyone. Since Semantic UI replaces an input with a different UI element, it would make sense (in my mind at least), if it did the focus redirection itself... If you make a PR, let me know and I'll +1 it!